# "Unable to find or create a directory of the trash" on NTFS partition

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, fstab, trash

I use RFRemix, desctop XFCE4

> ]$ uname -a
>   Linux localhost.localdomain 3.17.4-302.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 4 19:12:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When I try to delete from NTFS partition I get the error "Unable to find or create a directory of the trash." If it is not the trash, file can be deleted without any problems. The results of searching the information about this problem in the internet showed me that it might be fstab. I changed it  few times, but it didnt help. At the moment, I have the next fstab.

```
   /dev/disk/by-label/Prog       /media/Prog     ntfs-3g fmask=111,dmask=000,gid=1000,utf8       0 0
   /dev/disk/by-label/VACATION   /media/Vacation ntfs-3g fmask=111,dmask=000,gid=1000,utf8       0 0
   /dev/sda3                     /media/winnt    ntfs-3g fmask=111,dmask=000,gid=1000,utf8       0 0
```

Owner /media - my user (not root). Prog, Vacation, winnt - root and I can not change it (it doesn't show the error and it does not change)
Directories and files can be created easily in these partitions, so it has the access to the record.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to find or create a directory of the trash

Create a `.Trash-1000` subdirectory under each mountpoint:

```
mkdir /media/Prog/.Trash-$UID
mkdir /media/Vaction/.Trash-$UID
...
```

> I can not change it (it doesn't show the error and it does not change)

By default ntfs-3g works in "FAT mode", ignoring all POSIX permissions/ACLs. If you want, you can enable NTFS ACL support, but for that you should configure a [user mapping](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/user-mapping/) (to translate Windows SIDs to/from Linux UIDs).

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. In this case (if directory **.Trash-1000** exists on the disk root) the request as to the irrevocable delete of the file was displayed.